# Remove Duplicate Array and Merge The Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've an array of objects. I want don't want to render duplicates array but I want it's items to be merged with it's same one which is render example shown below.

Original Array

```
array = [
  {
    name: 'Test',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        product_name: "Kbana 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        product_name: "Kbana 2",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 3,
        product_name: "Kbana 3",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        product_name: "Kbana 4",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 5,
        product_name: "Kbana 5",
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        product_name: "Kbana 6",
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Now I have two same array objects which index is 1 and 2. Now I wants to merge index 2 items values with index 1. Like example below

```
array = [
      {
        name: 'Test',
        items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            product_name: "Kbana 1",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            product_name: "Kbana 2",
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Test 2',
        items: [
          {
            id: 3,
            product_name: "Kbana 3",
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            product_name: "Kbana 4",
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            product_name: "Kbana 5",
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            product_name: "Kbana 6",
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: 'Test',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        product_name: "Kbana 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        product_name: "Kbana 2",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 3,
        product_name: "Kbana 3",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        product_name: "Kbana 4",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 5,
        product_name: "Kbana 5",
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        product_name: "Kbana 6",
      },
    ]
  },
]

const newArr = [];

for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    var name = arr[i].name;
    for(var j = 0;j<arr.length;j++)
    {
       if(i != j)
       {
          if(name === arr[j].name)
          {
              arr[i].items = [...arr[i].items, ...arr[j].items]
              arr[j].name = "remove";
          }
       }
    }
}

arr = arr.filter(data => data.name !== "remove");

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: what if we want to push them as a object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the array elements by name.

We create an object map first, using the element.name as keys, then we use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to turn back into an array.

```js
array = [ { name: 'Test', items: [ { id: 1, product_name: "Kbana 1", }, { id: 2, product_name: "Kbana 2", }, ] }, { name: 'Test 2', items: [ { id: 3, product_name: "Kbana 3", }, { id: 4, product_name: "Kbana 4", }, ] }, { name: 'Test 2', items: [ { id: 5, product_name: "Kbana 5", }, { id: 6, product_name: "Kbana 6", }, ] }, ] 

// Use array.reduce and map to organise by name.
let result = Object.values(array.reduce((map, val) => { 
    if (!map[val.name]) { 
        map[val.name] = { name: val.name, items: [] };
    }
    map[val.name].items = map[val.name].items.concat(val.items);
    return map;
}, {}))

console.log("Result:", result);
```